# Is this a valid argument ? function floor property

Tags: discrete-mathematics, ceiling-and-floor-functions

*I'm new in that stuff in proving things. I'm always confused about when is a really valid reasoning. Then is this property, i appreciate any help.*

**Prove, for any real x:**

**x - 1 < $\lfloor$x$\rfloor$ $\leq$ x $\leq$ $\lceil$x$\rceil$ < x + 1**

by definition:

$\lfloor$x$\rfloor$ = n $\iff$ n $\leq$  x < n + 1

$\lceil$x$\rceil$ = n' $\iff$ n' - 1 < x $\leq$ n'

so, $\lfloor$x$\rfloor$ $\leq$ x $\leq$ $\lceil$x$\rceil$ , because  x $\leq$ n $\land$ x $\leq$ n'

( $\lfloor$x$\rfloor$ + 1 + (-1) > x + (-1) ) $\land$  ( $\lceil$x$\rceil$ - 1  + (1) < x + (1) )

($\lfloor$x$\rfloor$ > x - 1)   $\land$    ($\lceil$x$\rceil$  < x + 1)

Thereof, x - 1 < $\lfloor$x$\rfloor$ $\leq$ x $\leq$ $\lceil$x$\rceil$ < x + 1

Comment: Valid for sure.

Comment: @DuPhan thanks! So, whenever i use a < b < c, can i argue a $\land$ statement ?

Comment: Yes. In fact $a<b<c$ is really equivalent (at least I was taught so) to $a<b$ and $b<c$. Just a shorthand.